# Objects Rendering Black in Blender Render

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

[image: here it is]Now, I just got blender yesterday, and every time I render an animation, the objects always render black.

I have looked up stuff about it, but most of them are UV Maps, and I don't know what that is.

Comment: Hi, Jayson. Add lights to your scene.